# Jquery interacting with popup window

Tags: jquery, delegates, popup

I have a web page that loads my JQuery code into it. The same page has a link which opens a popup window.

I had an issue using the loaded JQuery and interacting with elements on my popup page. For a submit button I resolved it using :

`$("body").on('click', '#submitBtn', function(){
});`

I've now got a similar issue and need to understand how to get this working on my popup page:

```
$('#table').delegate('.deleteRow:not(#row .deleteRow)', 'click', function() {
});
```

The code is for a table row, clicking on a delete icon `class='deleteRow'` deletes selected row.

I'm not sure what to try.. anyone any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: what you are trying to achieve by `.deleteRow:not(#row .deleteRow)` selector?

Comment: also have you tried with `$("body").on('click', '.deleteRow:not(#row .deleteRow)', function(){` ?

Comment: @vijayP this worked...please add it as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: thanks @MacMan...!

Comment: @vijayP : yes add it in answer before someone else answers it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.delegate` can you try following way:

```
$("body").on('click', '.deleteRow:not(#row .deleteRow)', function(){

    //your code
});
```